# JS, создать объект в конструкторе класса?

Tags: javascript

Я могу создать объект в конструкторе класса? Если да, какой синтаксис?

```
    constructor() {
     this.constructorData = {
        arg: arg,
        arg1: arg1,
        arg2: arg2
     }
    }
```

Что-то вроде этого, записать все переменные в объект, чтобы удобнее передавать в метод, и уже в методе достать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создать объект в конструкторе класса. Что-то вроде этого:

```
constructor() {
  this.constructorData = {
    arg: arguments[0],
    arg1: arguments[1],
    arg2: arguments[2]
  };
}
```

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.constructorData = {
      arg : arguments[0],
      arg1: arguments[1],
      arg2: arguments[2]
    };
  }
}

var r = new MyClass(1, 2);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: спасибо, оказывается просто для одной переменной оставил = вместо : поэтому была ошибка, банальная невнимательность